# How to fix memory leak issue in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

**Problem:**

My App component is giving me an error like this.

```
D:\projects\myapp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:173 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
    in App (at renderApplication.js:45)
```

This is how my code looks like.

```
/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StatusBar} from 'react-native';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import RootNavigator from '_navigations/RootNavigator';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import store from '_store';
import Splashscreen from '_screens/splashscreen';
import axios from 'axios';
import refreshToken from '_store/actions/refreshToken';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.updateLoading();
    refreshToken();
  }

  updateLoading = async () => {
    const data = await this.performTimeConsumingTask();

    if (data !== null) {
      this.setState({isLoading: false});
    }
  };

  performTimeConsumingTask = async () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) =>
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve('result');
      }, 3000),
    );
  };

  render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return <Splashscreen />;
    }
    return (
      <>
        <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
        <Provider store={store}>
          <RootNavigator />
        </Provider>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

My splash screen is like this.

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Image} from 'react-native';

import styles from './splashstyle';

import logo from '_assets/img/logo.png';

const Splashscreen = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Image source={logo} style={styles.logo} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default Splashscreen;
```

As it is saying the issue is inside rendered method but I do not where I have done wrong. I tried a lot to find out what where I have done wrong but it is giving me this issue over and over. Can someone help me to solve this issue?Thank you

Comment: Ciao, how `Splashscreen` looks like? Can you show me?

Comment: Ciao, I asked an update because I supposed that your error came from a component that , while was unmounting, tries to modify his state. Seeing your code, I found that `Splashscreen` was unmounted when `this.state.isLoading` changes his value. But now I see that `Splashscreen` does not chages his state. Sorry for the waste of time. I will continue to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

if `performTimeConsumingTask` take so much time that the user moved to another screen(aka component) then the function `updateLoading` will continue its process which will try to `setState` in an unmounted component..
so you should cancel your work in `componentWillUnmount` to fix the issue

I would suggest some tweak like

```js
class MyComponent{
   
    constructor(){ ... this.isMounted = false; }
    
    componentDidMount(){ ... this.isMounted = true; }

    componentWillUnmount() { ... this.isMounted = false }

    // then inside updateLoading
    updateLoading = async () => {
    const data = await this.performTimeConsumingTask();

    if (this.isMounted && data !== null) { 
      // will protect set state against unmounted component
      this.setState({isLoading: false});
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Ciao, the `this.isMounted` workaround is a smart solution. Anyway, `RootNavigator` appears only after `this.state.isLoading` is setted to false. How can the user changes page before? I'm wrong?